# Where can I find Xcode crash reports?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode9

Looking for the crash reports for the Xcode process on macOS High Sierra.

Every thread is related to crashes on iOS which is not what 'm looking for, obviously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside **Applications/Utilities/Console**, open **User Reports** from the sidebar and search **Xcode** to find all Xcode-related crashes.

[image: Console - Xcode crashes]

If the sidebar is not visible, open it with **View/Show Sources** (<kbd>⌘0</kbd>) or by clicking on the icon on the top-left:

[image: Show Sources icon on the top left]